# Adding references to images to each row in google sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets

[image: Original Data]

I have a table above and I want to insert an image to each row (if and when the user wants to add).
However adding the image to the cell would not be good as the image will be v small and has to be resized.

I was wondering if there is a way to add the image into a new tab in the same workbook, that is mapping to each row.
Maybe automatically too if a flag in another column say image is mandatory.

[image: Output]

Comment: Your showing the image is the sample input? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect as the image?

Comment: The output would be something like the attached image 2. @Tanaike Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming, but using a web app and thus belongs on [WebApps.SE].

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. In your output situation, your 1st image is not changed? Do you just want to put an image on another sheet? Unfortunately, from your additional information, I couldn't still understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.